# Pandas DataFrame - row comparision and isolation problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have those DataFrame where I have fathers that are their own grandchild.
I want to isolate the corresponding rows to treat them separately.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'father' : ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'k'],
    'son' : ['b', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'j']
})
df
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'father' : [1, 2, 4, 11, 10, 5],
    'son' : [2, 1, 5, 10, 11, 6]
})
df2
```

We can see that in the first one we want to extract the rows where we find the values ab, ba and jk, kj, because `'a'` precedes `'b'` and `'b'` precedes `'a'`, idem for `'j'` and `'k'`.

Same thing in the second one with our integrates `1`, `2` and `10`, `11`.

I tried (in majority but not only) to use things like

`df[df[['FH', 'REM']].isin(df[['REM', 'FH']])]`

or

`df[df[['FH', 'REM']]==df[['REM', 'FH']]]`

Ineffectively.

My main problem is that I don't understand how to compare rows between them to do this.

Comment: My main problem is I don't understand what you are trying to do!!  What does "extract the rows where we find the values ab, ba and jk, kj, because 'a' precedes 'b' and 'b' precedes 'a', idem for 'j' and 'k'." really mean?  Can you explain with an example that includes row you want to extract as well as rows that get filtered?  Also, what does "I don't understand how to compare rows between them to do this." mean?  What them?  Compare how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `frozenset` to group your rows:

```
df['group'] = df.apply(frozenset, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
  father son   group
0      a   b  (a, b)
1      b   a  (a, b)
2      e   f  (e, f)
3      f   g  (g, f)
4      j   k  (j, k)
5      k   j  (j, k)
```

After, you can use a boolean mask:

```
m = df.groupby('group')['group'].transform('count') == 2
```

```
>>> df[m]
  father son   group
0      a   b  (a, b)
1      b   a  (a, b)
4      j   k  (j, k)
5      k   j  (j, k)

>>> df[~m]
  father son   group
2      e   f  (e, f)
3      f   g  (g, f)
```

Comment: I modified it a bit because I have some duplicates for a lot of father-son couples (each duplicate associated to different keys). It worked in this case with `df['group'] = df[['father', 'son']].drop_duplicates(subset=['father', 'son']).apply(frozenset, axis=1)`. I still have to check if some loops passed through this filter, but I think it's good.

Answer (score 0):

This will show all the rows that are their own grandchild in the same dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'father' : ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'k'],
    'son' : ['b', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'j']
})

print(df.loc[(df['father'].isin(df['son'])) & (df['son'].isin(df['father']))])
```

Result:

```
  father son
0      a   b
1      b   a
4      j   k
5      k   j
```